# How to process large log file in java

Tags: java

I have 4 files and each one is 200 MB. I have created 4 threads and  parallelly running 4 thread and each thread processing and adding in to Array blocking queue.

Some other thread is taking Array Blocking Queue and process and adding in to batch. The batch size is 5000 and executing batch and inserting records into database.But still its taking complete 4 files is around 6 mins to complete.

How increase performance in this case?

Comment: You probably need to show your implementation...

Comment: At this point we can only confirm that there might be something going wrong and guess what the problem might be. It is not possibly to answer this question to the extend defined by [answer]. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know... Processing 1GB with a blocking queue in 6 seconds *could* actually be good performance, depending on the hardware and the time it takes to process each element... We cannot have a good idea without having a sample of the input, the actual code and the hardware specification.

Comment: Put your input files on different harddiscs. In cases like this normally the hardware is the problem.

Comment: Get a profiler to see where your code spends its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure you have enough memory for queue+processor buffers+db buffers.

2) Batch size of 5k is a bit more than needed, in general you get up to speed in 100, not that iе makes much difference here though.

3) You can push data into oracle in multiple threads. Fetching sequences for ID fields population ahead, you'll be able to insert into 1 table in parallel, if you have not many indexes. Otherwise consider disabling/recalculating indexes, or insert into temporary table and then move everything into main one.

4) Take a look at oracle settings with fellow DB admin. Things like extend size/increase can change performance.

Comment: Why Oracle settings? OP does not say anything about a database, or am I blind?

Comment: @Robert In case he does, it might be helpful. If not, well, speeding up mysql is not  close enough to me anyway...

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can push data into oracle in multiple threads .you have any sample code for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no ready example, as my practices used custom libs for pooled executions. Nevertheless, if you don't care much about order of records, you can make several instances of your "other thread". They can share ArrayBlockingQueue and static strings, you only need to make sure they don't use common static vars for other things. Don't forget to commit inserts (important for multiple threads), and see if it improves performance.

Comment: If I am increasing batch size 5000 to 7000 initially its time taking 500 ms insert in to database. later on words time keep on increasing to 1000 ms,2000 ms,3000 ms ...  why its behaving like this

Comment: @madhusudhan It's hard to tell exactly, but most common causes of performance degradation for inserts are indexes, constraints and triggers with look-up code.

Comment: @Alexander Anikin Yes It's performance degradation.I am planing do with master salve architecture. Please let me know I am in to the right path or else I want to go different approach.